# retrieve vhdx path from a remote server

Tags: powershell

hi i' m trying to retrieve the vhdx of specified vmname from the remote host server

here part of the script

```
$pth="C:\path\resize-vm"
    $list=gc $pth\list-host.txt
    foreach ($hostserver in $list) {
    $vm=(Invoke-Command -ComputerName $hostserver -ScriptBlock {Get-VM}).VMName
     Write-Host -NoNewline   " here the vm installed in "  $hostserver  `r`n $vm

    $vmname=Read-Host -Prompt "please chose a vmname to resize  "

#the issue in the last line 

    $pathvhd=Invoke-Command -ComputerName $hostserver -ScriptBlock {(Get-VMHardDiskDrive -VMName $vmname).path}
```

When I launch this command `$vmname="dc-kozhan"`
I am getting this error

> Cannot validate argument on parameter 'VMName'. The argument is null
>   or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try
>   the command again.
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-VMHardDiskDrive], ParameterBindingValidationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.HyperV.PowerShell.Commands.GetVMHardDiskDrive
>   Command
>       + PSComputerName        : h-uludag-3

But when I specified `dc-kozhan` literally it work

```
    PS C:\Users> Invoke-Command -ComputerName $hostserver -ScriptBlock {(Get-VMHardDiskDrive -VMName "DC-KOZAHAN")
    .path}
V:\DC-KOZAHAN\DC-KOZAHAN-SYSTEM.vhdx
V:\DC-KOZAHAN\DC-KOZAHAN-DIRECTORY.vhdx
V:\DC-KOZAHAN\DC-KOZAHAN-SYSVOL.vhdx
V:\DC-KOZAHAN\DC-KOZAHAN-BACKUP.vhdx
```

does anyone have an idea why it does not work when it's specified in a variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to understand how to pass arguments inside the scriptblock. The scope is different when you try to pass the value inside the scriptblock. As a result, **$VMname** is becoming null in your first statement. 
Kindly change your existing `Invoke-command` statement to the below one:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $hostserver -ScriptBlock {Param([string]$vmname)(Get-VMHardDiskDrive -VMName $vmname)} -ArgumentList $vmname
```

Also, my suggestion for you to read about the `argumentlist` in powershell in case `invoke-command`

Hope it helps.